# want to change an img to an link, how can i do this?

Tags: javascript

I created an img with createElement. After the insert it should be possible to Change the Attribute. That's not the Problem, because every img have an id. so i can Change the property / Attribute.

but now, after the insert of the img it should be possible, that the img get an href. so when somebody click the img another site should be open.

How can I append arround the img an "a href"? and how can i delete it?

I have no idea, how i can append, overwrite or delete an existing html element.

Comment: Do you specifically need to dynamically change images into links and then back to plain images again? Or are you asking how to create an anchor that contains an image as a once-off?

Comment: yes dynamic Change an Image into links

Answer (score 0):

you can use this simple code !

```html
<img onClick="location.href='https://jsfiddle.net/'" src="http://doc.jsfiddle.net/_downloads/jsfiddle-logo.png" alt="">
```